# How to use vertical scrolling using robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

Which method or keyword is used for vertical scrolling using robot framework
I tried
Execute javascript window.scrollto(document.body.scrollheight, 0)

Comment: What is it you want to achieve, what do you observe your current code example does, why doesn't it fit your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might be in trouble of running "Set Focus To Element" SeleniumLibrary command with Firefox browser. Please try following ways to scroll according to your requirement. There are few others ways to do the same with javascripts and also using xpath if theres no clear attributes like IDs, Classes in the DOM.

```
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
Execute JavaScript    document.getElementById("${ElementID}").scrollIntoView()
Execute JavaScript    document.getElementsByClassName("${ElementClass}")[0].scrollIntoView()
```